# Jenkins pipeline - Remove @tmp folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using "Workspace Cleanup Plugin" to clean workspace after the job finishes. But still `@tmp` directory is not deleted.

Any way we can delete this `@tmp` folder using pipeline script.

It looks like a known issue as far as I see in Jira:

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44909
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41805

Comment: You failed to point out where you see this directory. When Project@tmp is found on the jenkins MASTER it is used if you Replay the Project pipeline. Deleting the directory would save space, but cause functional loss.

Answer (score 10):

I used custom workspace in Jenkins then deleteDir() will not delete @tmp folder.

So to delete @tmp along with workspace use following

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            customWorkspace "/home/jenkins/jenkins_workspace/${JOB_NAME}_${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        }
    }
    post {
        cleanup {
            /* clean up our workspace */
            deleteDir()
            /* clean up tmp directory */
            dir("${workspace}@tmp") {
                deleteDir()
            }
            /* clean up script directory */
            dir("${workspace}@script") {
                deleteDir()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This snippet will work for default workspace also.**

Comment: Wouldn't this command "dir(${workspace}@tmp)" generates an extra folder "${workspace}@tmp@tmp"? At least this is what I see when I try it.

Comment: For me I will use this command: sh "rmdir -v ${possibleTmpFolderPath} || true". If the tmp folder is not empty, won't remove it(although the tmp folder should be empty). Add "|| true" to ensure even if the command "rmdir" fails, the code won't break.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to your question, but might help someone.

If you are using the [dir](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#dir-change-current-directory) Jenkins pipeline step to change directories, then you'll see these `@tmp` folders getting created. Instead, use the `cd` command and they won't get created in the first place.

So, instead of,

```
def myFunc(String folder) {
  dir(folder) {
   // work
  }
}
```

Do this.

```
def myFunc(String folder) {
  bat "cd ${folder}"
  // work
}
```

Comment: I'm having the @tmp folders issue with both dir(folder) and cd folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **deleteDir()** as the last step of the pipeline Jenkinsfile (assuming you didn't change the working directory).

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet works great.

```
//@tmp clean up
stage ('cleanup') 
{
  withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin']) {
  dir('<your directory path>') {
  sh "rm -rf <directory `enter code here`name>@tmp"
  }
  }
}
```