# What are the @tmp folders in a Jenkins workspace and how to clean them up

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline, for a PHP project in a Docker container. This is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      agent any
      steps {
        sh 'docker-compose up -d'
        sh 'docker exec symfony composer install'
      }
    }
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'docker exec symfony php ./bin/phpunit --coverage-clover=\'reports/coverage/coverage.xml\' --coverage-html=\'reports/coverage\' --coverage-crap4j=\'reports/crap4j.xml\''
      }
    }
    stage('Coverage') {
      steps {
        step([$class: 'CloverPublisher', cloverReportDir: '/reports/coverage', cloverReportFileName: 'coverage.xml'])
      }
    }
  }  
  post {
    cleanup {
      sh 'docker-compose down -v'
      cleanWs()
    }
  }
}
```

After running the pipeline, the `var/lib/jenkins/workspace` folder contains 4 folders (assuming my project name is `Foo`):

1. Foo
2. Foo@2
3. Foo@2@tmp
4. Foo@tmp

What are these, and how do I clean them up? `cleanWs` does not remove any except the first of them after the build.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297411/jenkins-pipeline-remove-tmp-folder) because

- That question does not answer my question: what are these files.
- The answers to that question suggest using `deleteDir`, which is [not recommended](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41894) when using Docker containers.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297411/jenkins-pipeline-remove-tmp-folder

Comment: @mkemmerz I have updated my question with information as to why this is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an opened [Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41805) about deleteDir() not deleting the @tmp/@script/@... directories.

A workaround to delete those:

```
post {
  always {
    cleanWs()
    dir("${env.WORKSPACE}@tmp") {
      deleteDir()
    }
    dir("${env.WORKSPACE}@script") {
      deleteDir()
    }
    dir("${env.WORKSPACE}@script@tmp") {
      deleteDir()
    }
  }
}
```

There is also a [comment](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41805?focusedCommentId=383965&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-383965) on the issue describing what *@tmp* is:

> It [@tmp folder] contains the content of any library that was loaded at
>   run time. Without a copy, Replay can't work reliably.

Comment: How would I achieve the same if my pipeline is using 2 agents? I want to cleanup these dirs on both the agents.

Answer (score 7):

The
Foo@2
Foo@2@tmp
folders were created because the agent was defined 2 times. Once it was defined at the top level inside the pipeline block. And once inside the stage called build.
The working folder of stage 'build' is the Foo@2 folder.

Comment: This really helped my to remove @2 folder but not @tmp

Comment: Yes, but Viktor Be in his comment has already explained how to delete the @tmp folder in a pipeline job.

Comment: this is a great answer! I'm having a problem right now where the @2 folder appears without using a parallel build, and it turns out it's because I've duplicated the agent definition

Comment: You are superhero. Your answer helped me a lot. God bless you