# What is the purpose of a @tmp folder (created with java)

Tags: java

When creating a folder using *java*. For this I'm using the following lines of code:

```java
String tempDirectoryName = packageName + "-tempworkingdir";
this.temporalDir = new File("/tmp/" + tempDirectoryName);
this.temporalDir.mkdirs();
```

This works flawless. On my function end, I just call

```java
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(this.temporalDir);
```

to delete the same folder.

---

I discovered that somehow a "temporal" folder with an appended *@tmp* gets created. An `ls -l` on my *tmp*-Folder shows this folder. Also, after calling `deleteDirectory` this folder persists.

```
/tmp/package-tempworkingdir@tmp
```

Since I haven't found anything about this folders, I was hoping someone can enlighten me.

I'm not quite sure why this folder is needed, and I was wondering **why** this folder even gets created (it is empty, at least after calling `deleteDirectory`). Also, is there a **safe way to delete** it or avoid its creation?

---

Edit: You can avoid the creation with `mkdir()` instead of `mkdirs()`.

Comment: With Java 7 onwards you can also just use `Files.createTempDirectory()`

Comment: I know, I also tried this at first. This also creates such a ```@tmp``` folder and because of that I switch to the ```mkdirs``` method. Actually, I want to know whty this folder is even created and secondly if there is a possibility to avoid this.

Comment: Does this happen on Jenkins? because there seems to be some issues regarding the `@tmp` during a jenkins build: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58588794/what-are-the-tmp-folders-in-a-jenkins-workspace-and-how-to-clean-them-up and on their tracker: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52750

Comment: Yes, happens on Jenkins. But thanks, since it seems to be an issue I'll leave it for now.