# Jenkins declarative pipeline @tmp folders

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'd try to understand the root cause of reason why Jenkins creates such directories as below.. When I try to find coverage report, I realise that it is located in my-application-ms@2 rather than my-application-ms. Meanwhile I checked rest of directories abd there is only SecretFiles which is empty.

So what is the best way to delete rest of directories which current directory should be always **my-application-ms** .. Should I specify the each dir in post section ?Is there any doubt to delete rest of directories?

- my-application-ms
- my-application-ms@2
- my-application-ms@2@tmp
- my-application-ms@tmp

---

```
 post{
    failure{
        notifyBuild('FAILED')
    }
    success{
        notifyBuild('SUCCESSFUL')
    }
    aborted{
        notifyBuild('FAILED')
    }
    always {
        deleteDir() /* clean up our workspace */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should rather use special `step` type for workspace clean up. [`cleanWs`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ws-cleanup/#cleanws-delete-workspace-when-build-is-done) should do the job for you.

Comment: ,Should I specifiy the directory or does it handle itself?

Comment: You don't need to specify directory.

Comment: it worked but its only delete my-application-ms folder whereas ı'd like to delete rest of @tmp folders

Comment: I think it will delete your current workspace, whatever it is without touching other (created in the past)  instances of workspace for this job. When you first clean up your workspace area and use `cleanWs` since then, it should do all you wanted. Disclaimer: that's my guess, not an actual experience.

Answer (score 0):

cleanWS() only deletes de Workspace main folder, not @tmp nor @script folders. So you have to delete them by yourself.
Also, please note that there is an special cleanup step. Don't use Post step since you may perform some other operations here. cleanup will be fired after post step

```
cleanup
{
    cleanWs()
    dir("${WORKSPACE}@tmp"){
        deleteDir()
    }
    dir("${WORKSPACE}@script"){
        deleteDir()
    }
}
```

Source: [Jenkins pipeline - Remove @tmp folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297411/jenkins-pipeline-remove-tmp-folder)